# Immediate sibling selector misunderstanding

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="player">
    <div class="frame" data-aspect="4:3">
    </div>

    <div class="seeker">
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
    </div>

    <div class="extra-controls">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I was trying to access `.seeker` with the following selector:

```
#player .frame + #player .seeker
{
    margin-top: 1em;

    height: 50px;

    background-color: #575757;

    color: white;
}
```

Which [did not style the `.seeker` element (link to fiddle no. 1)](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/Ea3eF/), where without the `#player` [it did (link to fiddle no. 2)](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/Ea3eF/1/):

```
#player .frame + .seeker
{
    margin-top: 1em;

    height: 50px;

    background-color: #575757;

    color: white;
}
```

I am confused, because selecting directly, without `+` [it selects the element (link to fiddle no. 3)](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/Ea3eF/2/), so, there is a match for the `#player .seeker`.

**Note:** Each of the fiddles has almost identical results, but, their CSS is a little different.

What is happening here?

Comment: Probably because it is looking for a sibling with `id="player"` which it can't find. After which it would then try to look for a child with `class="seeker"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sibling selector is relative to the selector up to that point. It does not start from the top of the document again. So `#player .frame + .seeker` is correct. Specifying `#player` is like typing `#player #player ...`.

Answer (score 3):

`#player .frame + #player .seeker` is not going to work because it is looking for a #player that is a sibling of .frame inside **another** #player.

What you want is probably `#player .frame + .seeker`, which will select a .seeker that is an immediately following sibling of .frame inside #player.

Check out http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html for some more examples

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="sibling">
    FOO
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="sibling">
      BAR
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For this structure, `.parent .child + .sibling` selector will find the one filled with 'FOO'. But selector written the same as yours  - `.parent .child + .parent .sibling` - will find the one filled with 'BAR' ([**proof**](http://jsfiddle.net/r3Zvs/)).

The point is, `+` is just an operator - as `>` and  (a whitespace) are. It does not "group" its operands.